# Markdown live preview in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, markdown

Are there any Javascript Markdown editing toolbars or libraries that show the live preview within the textarea and hide the formatting marks (**, ___ etc), similar to [TinyMCE's](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php) implementation?

If not, how would I go about implementing this in jQuery?

I'm currently using [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/), which only shows the preview **after** the textarea, or in a pop-up.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617093/displaying-markdown-in-my-textarea) refering to 'BlueCloth' sounds close, but although im interested in general implementation a RoR version isn't very useful at this stage (I'm using Python/Zope).

I'm aware that most of the beauty of Markdown is it's simple text formatting characters, but the site in question is fairly non-technical and I'm largely using the Markdown Python library for it's 'evil' html stipping abilities.

UPDATE: In response to comments, I suppose I'd be happy for the formatting marks to display if *typed*, but not if the toolbar is used (i.e. I'm assuming GUI users are less technical users).

Or, other toolbars have a 'source' view, which might be an option.

Comment: Have you checked these js plugins?
 https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/markdown%20editor/

Answer (score 1):

if you need markdown support right in textarea with no additional GUI, then [textarea-markdown](https://github.com/komagata/textarea-markdown) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I found [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked),
and here is the [js file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js).
very easy to use, you just add the library in `script` tag, and use `marked.parse()` function

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        target.innerHTML = marked.parse("#Example");
  </script>
```

### Example

**Run the snippet and write something in `textarea`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="textareaID">
# Example Title
## list
1. one
1. tow
1. three

  </textarea>
  <div id="content"></div>
  
  <script>
    $("#textareaID").on('input', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
          marked.parse(e.target.value);
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) might be too heavy, but it is nice.

Comment: Does it use Markdown? Can't find any obvious reference to it on the site.

Comment: On a related note, good to see FCKEditor finally got renamed ;)

Comment: CKEditor is a fully JS implementation that uses iFrames.  No underlying technology or software.  (They even have their own library of JS functions.)

Answer (score -5):

The only way you can achieve it is using an `iframe`.

Comment: but not in internet explorer @ Jon Hadley